# Windows 11 - Calculator and Settings need 3 clicks on app icon in taskbar to appear on desktop

Tags: taskbar, windows-11

I upgraded last week to Windows 11.

- Starting with an empty desktop.
- I click on the Calculator or Settings icon in the taskbar. They seem to start - wide line underneath.
- I don't see the app on the desktop.
- I click a second time, which probably is a "hide" click in Windows logic - narrow line underneath.
- Third click, and I see the app.

I've tried this several times, happens each time.

- A variation: If I start Calculator, then open Excel, then I need another 3 clicks to see Calculator appear.
- Starting from a desktop icon gives the same result. Right-clicking the icon, choosing Properties, the *run* option is set to "Normal window".

This doesn't happen with apps like Powershell, Excel, WSL. They appear with 1 click on the desktop.

Is this a bug or how can I fix this?

Comment: Right-click the icons and select *Properties > Shortcut*. Is the Run field set to "Normal window"?

Comment: @harrymc, I dragged the icon from the app-list to the desktop. Right-clicked, choosing Properties, it showed "normal window". I then started the app from the desktop shortcut - same problem. (Right-clicking the icon in the taskbar doesn't show a properties option.)

Comment: Dies this happen when booting in Safe mode?